# How get permission for camera in android.(Specifically Marshmallow)

Tags: android, camera

Hey I am designing  an app in android studio. In which i require permission of camera. I have included `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`
  in the the AndroidManifest.xml file. It is working properly in all versions of android except Marshmallow. How do I get camera permission by default? If not possible how do I ask it from user?

Comment: Refer to this link: https://github.com/sagarjogadia28/PermissionSample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/sagarjogadia28/com/permissionsample/MainActivity.java

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 96, accepted):

First check if the user has granted the permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
```

Then, you could use this to request to the user:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, requestCode);
```

And in Marshmallow, it will appear in a dialog

Comment: Thanks alot... :-) It asks for permisson now.

Comment: You are welcome. Please, if the answer helps you, check as solution ;)

Comment: In `Manifest.permission.CAMERA` i am getting red text of `CAMERA`

Comment: use android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA

Comment: In 2023 this is outdated. Call requestPermissions directly on your AppCompatActivity object. Don't use a static method. See other answers.

Comment: requestPermissions is also depreciated. Use registerForActivityResult

Comment: Can you please tell me what will be the corresponding code for accessing camera if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R`, i.e., Android is 11(R) or above?

Answer (score 65):

You can try the following code to request camera permission in marshmallow. First check if the user grant the permission. If user has not granted the permission, then request the camera permission:

```
private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

After requesting the permission, dialog will display to ask permission containing `allow` and `deny` options. After clicking action we can get result of the request with the following method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what will be the corresponding code for accessing camera if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R`, i.e., Android is 11(R) or above?

Answer (score 7):

This works for me, the source is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=es-419)

```
int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA=0;
// Here, this is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
     if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
     {

     }
     else
     {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA );
          // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
          // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
          // result of the request.
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what will be the corresponding code for accessing camera if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R`, i.e., Android is 11(R) or above?

Answer (score 3):

```
check using this
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
```

and

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest way to take permission is to used the deterex library. like below
Implement the following library in your gradle.

```
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.2'
```

after adding the library used this for permission like below

```
        Dexter.withContext(this)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
        @Override public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {/* ... */}
        @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {/*
        ... */}
    }).check();
```

Don't forget to add the user permission in your manifest

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I try to add following code:

```
private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

On onCreate Function and this following code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this worked for me :)

Comment: Can you please tell me what will be the corresponding code for accessing camera if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R`, i.e., Android is 11(R) or above?

Answer (score 1):

Requesting Permissions
In the following code, we will ask for camera permission:

in java

EasyPermissions is a wrapper library to simplify basic system permissions logic when targeting Android M or higher.

Installation
EasyPermissions is installed by adding the following dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {

    // For developers using AndroidX in their applications
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'

    // For developers using the Android Support Library
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:2.0.1'

}


private void askAboutCamera(){

        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this,
                "A partir deste ponto a permissão de câmera é necessária.",
                CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[click here](https://codingmitra.com/camera-and-gallery) for full source code and learn more.

Before get permission you can check api version,

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
  {
      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

      } 
      else
      {
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 401);
      }
  }
  else
  {
    // if version is below m then write code here,          
  }
```

Get the Result of the permission dialog,

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 401) {
        if (grantResults.length == 0 || grantResults == null) {

        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            openGallery();
        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        }
    } else if (requestCode == 402) {
        if (grantResults.length == 0 || grantResults == null) {

        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what will be the corresponding code for accessing camera if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R`, i.e., Android is 11(R) or above?

Answer (score 0):

```
         private const val CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 2323

         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) 
           {
             if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != 
             PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
               {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 
            CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
               }
           }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what will be the corresponding code for accessing camera if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R`, i.e., Android is 11(R) or above?