# Camera permission not automatically granted

Tags: android, camera

I try to access camera using Camera.open()
But it throws exception **Fail to connect to camera service.**

I checked camera permission in Settings->Apps->MyApp->Permission->Camera and it's not granted.
I have already added camera permission in android manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true"/>
```

Why is it not automatically granted at the first time ?
What is the best practice to handle this ?

Comment: You'll need to request permissions during the runtime. For that, you can use my library: https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if the user grant the permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
```

Then, you could use this to request to the user:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, requestCode);
```

And in marshmallow and later, it appears the dialog

---

After requesting the permission alert will display to ask permission contains allow and deny options. After clicking action we can get result of the request with the following method.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't believe me, I have taken the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552144/how-get-permission-for-camera-in-android-specifically-marshmallow).