# Application wont ask for camera permission

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Application for Android devices and I wanted to scan QR codes, but I have one problem, it just wont ask for the Camera permission, therefore the **`surfaceview`** just stays black.

My Code:

```
public class ScanQR extends AppCompatActivity {

private SurfaceView surfaceView;
private CameraSource cameraSource;
private TextView textView;
private BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_qr);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.scanQR);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScanQr);

    barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();

    cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector).setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480).build();

    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            } try {
                cameraSource.start(holder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            cameraSource.stop();
        }
    });

    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {

        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            SparseArray<Barcode> qrCodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

            if(qrCodes.size() > 0){
                textView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(1000);
                        textView.setText(qrCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.estcers.partygooo">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CreateParty" />
    <activity android:name=".SearchUser" />
    <activity android:name=".UserInfo" />
    <activity android:name=".Friends" />
    <activity android:name=".PendingFriends" />
    <activity android:name=".Parties" />
    <activity android:name=".Invitations" />
    <activity android:name=".Entries" />
    <activity android:name=".PendingAssistances" />
    <activity android:name=".PartyInfo" />
    <activity android:name=".GetQR" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="barcode" />

    <activity android:name=".ScanQR"></activity>
</application>
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ScanQR"
android:orientation="vertical">

<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300sp"
    android:id="@+id/scanQR"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="100sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tvScanQr"
    android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

If anyone could help me with this problem I would be really grateful, I just have no clue of what is going on.

I also have the implementation: 
`"implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'"` and `google()`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to request for the camera permission, if it is not provided. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552144/how-get-permission-for-camera-in-android-specifically-marshmallow

Comment: I've just seen that but I dont understand this line: `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, requestCode);` I should put that line inside the If? activity = Activity.class? and what is requestCode?

Comment: Request Code is just a special int like an ID for your apps request mechanism just any random number will do.And you should put it in an if to check if permission is already granted or not

Comment: This link Contains example of vision library for QR Scan. https://www.truiton.com/2016/09/android-example-programmatically-scan-qr-code-and-bar-code/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275906/how-to-ask-runtime-permissions-for-camera/52201117#52201117

Answer (score 0):

When you're about to open the camera, include the following check:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(YourCameraActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
```

and handle the result with:

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "The app requires that permission in order to work properly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

and in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```